# Why does my keras neural network model output different values on a different machine?

Tags: amazon-ec2, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am using aws ec2 to train a model for a multi-label classification task. After training , I tested the model on the same machine which gives me good results (accuracy of 90+%). However, after I imported the saved model into my local machine (no GPU), it gives different results (accuracy is less than 5%). Any suggestions on why this is happening? Thanks.

TL;DR: ***Keras/tensorflow*** model produces different results when transfered **from GPU** machine **to CPU**.

Comment: So what data are you training your model with and depends hhow to programmed it to do it.

Comment: I'm working with text data (tweets). I'm classifying them based on emotions they express(joy, sadness, anger, etc.). I am using keras over tensorflow. My network is a sequencial model (embedding layer-> bidirectional LSTM-> sigmoid dense layer). I'm using binary_crossentropy (since I want to have multiple 0/1 emotion output) and rmsprop for the optimiser. It's working great in aws but not in my local machine.

Comment: I already changed the version of keras and tensorflow on my local machine to same of that in aws. The only difference now is that I'm using a CPU version on my laptop while aws ec2 uses a gpu. However, output in my local machine still tends to give a very different output as compared to aws.

Comment: You should provide code and what results you are getting, else the question is completely unanswerable.

Comment: Sir @MatiasValdenegro, My code is based from this [github code](https://github.com/alexander-rakhlin/CNN-for-Sentence-Classification-in-Keras/blob/master/trainGraph.py) posted by Sir Alexander Rakhlin. I modified it to use RNN instead for multiple emotion output. I was getting a good result of 90+% accuracy on the aws ec2 machine while only 5% on my laptop which doesn't have a GPU. I did some searching about this behavior and found that the cause is the cuDNN used on the GPU machine producing non-deterministic values which randomizes the model. I posted the solution I found with some links.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Upon searching the net, I found the problem. It seems like that keras over tensorflow when running on a GPU tends to produce results that are not reproducible when transfered to a non-GPU machine. This most likely has something to do with the cuDNN installed. cuDNN's maxpooling and some convolution backward algorithm is non-deterministic - as said from a forum.

Solutions I found say the use of `numpy.random.seed(seed_no)` right before calling any keras libraries. This works when you run the code **on a CPU**. Works with both *keras/theano* and *keras/tensorflow*.

Solution for **GPU users** using keras over theano involves [modifying the .theanorc file into](https://www.kaggle.com/c/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/discussion/22637#130118):

```
[dnn.conv]
algo_bwd_filter = deterministic
algo_bwd_data = deterministic
```

Or [using theano flags](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2479#issuecomment-213987747): `THEANO_FLAGS="dnn.conv.algo_bwd_filter=deterministic,dnn.conv.algo_bwd_data=deterministic" python rnn_model.py`

However, I haven't found any clear instructions yet of how to produce uniform results on a keras with tensorflow as back-end running on a GPU.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer!
What is the parameter seed_no for numpy.random.seed ?

And do you know why calling it will stop cuDNN to be nondeterministic ?
Thanks!

Comment: Sir @Pusheen_the_dev, seed_no is an integer variable you use to control the random state of numpy making the result predictable. You can see more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do). As far as I know, keras uses numpy to randomize the initial weights of the model. Thus, setting a seed to control this random state will make the output of the model produce uniform results for experiments. However, seeding will not stop the cuDNN from being non-deterministic since it is the default setting when installed. You can use theano flags for this.