# np.random.seed need to be called every time

Tags: python, numpy

Following two version code should have given the same output. Looks like np.random.seed need to be called every time. Is it correct?

**Is there any way to set seed once so that same random number generated everytime**

```
np.random.seed(0)
for _ in range(10):
    print(np.random.randint(low=1, high=100))
```

Output:
45
48
65
68
68
10
84
22
37
88

```
for _ in range(10):
    np.random.seed(0)
    print(np.random.randint(low=1, high=100))
```

Output: 45
45
45
45
45
45
45
45
45
45

Comment: Er.. in the first version you set the seed once and then repeatedly request a random value, in the second you set the seed on every iteration and then request a random value which will be same every time, what are you expecting?

Comment: well, no. if you seed right before randint you get the same value all the time

Comment: "Following two version code should have given the same output." why?

Comment: The two code blocks should not give the same output. Check this answer for a nice explanation of what np.random.seed(0) does: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do

Comment: I have edited the question to add - "Is there any way to set seed once so that same random number generated evrytime"

Comment: @Shiv, Then what is the point of using random number generatorm at each step. You can just do `a = np.random.randint()` once and use this variable afterwards.

Comment: @Seljuk , The need is there so that we set once in global header file and all team member will get same random number everytime.

Comment: FYI: If you use a random-ish value to seed np.random this wouldn't happen. For example: with `from timeit import default_timer as tmr` and `np.random.seed(int(tmr()*100000) % 11)` you'll get (seemingly) random values based on the current time even if you seed the RNG before every call to `randint`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using a cryptographically secure random number generator, random numbers are not really random. You are using a *pseudo* random number generator, which means you are iterating over a fixed table of predefined numbers. Seeding the random number means choosing the entry in that table you want to use first. Seeding it *every time* before you create a random number *to the same position* means you will always get the same number.