# Dynamic pandas dataframe generation

Tags: python, pandas

Here is code I wrote to generate a dataframe that contains 4 columns

```
num_rows = 10

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'id_col' : [x+1 for x in range(num_rows)] , 'c1': [randint(0, 9) for x in range(num_rows)], 'c2': [randint(0, 9) for x in range(num_rows)], 'c3': [randint(0, 9) for x in range(num_rows)] })
df
```

`print(df)` renders :

```
id_col  c1  c2  c3
0       1   3   1   5
1       2   0   2   4
2       3   1   2   5
3       4   0   5   6
4       5   0   0   1
5       6   6   5   8
6       7   1   6   8
7       8   5   8   8
8       9   1   5   2
9      10   2   9   2
```

I've set the number or rows to be dynamically generated via the `num_rows` variable.

How to dynamically generate 1000 columns where each column is prepended by 'c'. So columns `c1,c2,c3....c1000` are generated where each columns contains 10 rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better performance I suggest use for create `DataFrame` numpy function [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and then change columns names by list comprehension, for new column by position use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html):

```
np.random.seed(458)

N = 15
M = 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(M, N)))
df.columns = ['c{}'.format(x+1) for x in df.columns]
df.insert(0, 'idcol', np.arange(M))

print (df)
   idcol  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14  c15
0      0   8   2   1   6   2   1   0   9   7    8    0    5    5    6    0
1      1   0   2   5   0   0   2   5   2   9    2    1    0    0    5    0
2      2   5   1   3   5   4   5   3   0   2    1    7    8    9    5    4
3      3   8   7   7   0   1   3   6   7   5    8    8    9    8    5    5
4      4   2   8   1   7   3   7   4   6   0    7    0    9    4    0    4
5      5   9   2   1   6   1   9   5   6   7    4    6    1    7    3    7
6      6   1   9   3   9   7   7   2   7   9    8    2    7    2    5    5
7      7   7   6   6   6   4   2   9   0   6    5    7    0    0    4    9
8      8   6   4   2   1   3   1   7   0   4    3    0    5    4    7    7
9      9   1   3   5   7   2   2   1   5   6    1    9    5    9    6    3
```

Another solution with [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) for stack first `id` column to 2d array:

```
np.random.seed(458)

arr = np.hstack([np.arange(M)[:, None], np.random.randint(10, size=(M, N))])
df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
df.columns = ['idcol'] + ['c{}'.format(x) for x in df.columns[1:]]
print (df)
   idcol  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14  c15
0      0   8   2   1   6   2   1   0   9   7    8    0    5    5    6    0
1      1   0   2   5   0   0   2   5   2   9    2    1    0    0    5    0
2      2   5   1   3   5   4   5   3   0   2    1    7    8    9    5    4
3      3   8   7   7   0   1   3   6   7   5    8    8    9    8    5    5
4      4   2   8   1   7   3   7   4   6   0    7    0    9    4    0    4
5      5   9   2   1   6   1   9   5   6   7    4    6    1    7    3    7
6      6   1   9   3   9   7   7   2   7   9    8    2    7    2    5    5
7      7   7   6   6   6   4   2   9   0   6    5    7    0    0    4    9
8      8   6   4   2   1   3   1   7   0   4    3    0    5    4    7    7
9      9   1   3   5   7   2   2   1   5   6    1    9    5    9    6    3
```

Comment: may i know why `np.random.seed(458)`

Comment: @pyd sure, it is usefull if want same output of np.random, it is used for testing. But if remove it get also different values, better in real code. You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21494489/2901002)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, use `str.format` and dict comprehension

```
num_rows = 10
num_cols = 15

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'c{}'.format(n):  [randint(0, 9) for x in range(num_rows)] for n in range(num_cols)}, 
                  index=[x+1 for x in range(num_rows)] , )
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9
1   1   6   2   1   3   1   8   8   2   0
2   2   6   2   2   5   7   4   1   6   2
3   1   2   6   8   7   5   5   7   2   2
4   5   5   3   3   4   7   8   1   8   6
5   7   2   8   6   5   6   2   0   0   4
6   8   2   4   4   6   3   0   1   0   2
7   5   6   8   5   1   0   4   8   4   7
8   1   5   4   5   2   4   4   6   2   7
9   5   7   7   8   5   0   2   7   3   2
10  4   8   5   3   3   7   5   1   5   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `np.random.randint` to create a full array of random values, f-strings (Python 3.6+) with a list comprehension for column naming, and `pd.DataFrame.assign` with `np.arange` for defining "id_col":

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

rows = 10
cols = 5
minval, maxval = 0, 10

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(minval, maxval, (rows, cols)),
                  columns=[f'c{i}' for i in range(1, cols+1)])\
       .assign(id_col=np.arange(1, num_rows+1))

print(df)

   c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  id_col
0   8   4   6   0   8       1
1   8   3   5   9   0       2
2   1   3   3   6   2       3
3   6   4   1   1   7       4
4   3   7   0   9   5       5
5   4   6   8   8   6       6
6   0   3   9   9   7       7
7   0   6   1   2   4       8
8   3   7   1   2   0       9
9   6   6   0   5   8      10
```