# random_state parameter in sklearn's train_test_split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

What difference does different values of random state makes to the output? For instance, if I set 0 and if I set 100 what difference would it make to the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html):

> The `random_state` is the seed used by the random number generator.

In general a seed is used to create reproducible outputs. In the case of `train_test_split` the `random_state` determines how your data set is split. 
Unless you want to create reproducible runs, you can skip this parameter.

> For instance, if is set 0 and if i set 100 what difference would it
>   make to the output ?

You will always get the same train/test split for a specific seed. Different seeds will result in a different train/test split.

Answer (score 0):

Passing different integers to `random_state` seeds NumPy's pseudo random number generator with those values and [makes the resulting "random" train and test data reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do).  This means that if you pass the function array `a` with `random_seed=0`, using that 0 seed value will always result in the same train and test data.

When you pass an integer, the value eventually gets pass to [`scklearn.utils.check_random_state()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5431a1a9bfaf1927fade31492ac2b63423ad6384/sklearn/utils/validation.py#L791), which becomes:

```
if isinstance(seed, (numbers.Integral, np.integer)):
    return np.random.RandomState(seed)
```

This in turn is used by a class like [`ShuffleSplit`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/5431a1a9bfaf1927fade31492ac2b63423ad6384/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py#L1345) to call a random permutation:

```
rng = check_random_state(self.random_state)
for i in range(self.n_splits):
    # random partition
    permutation = rng.permutation(n_samples)
    ind_test = permutation[:n_test]
    ind_train = permutation[n_test:(n_test + n_train)]
    yield ind_train, ind_test
```

Here's an example using the actual method that is used:

```
>>> np.random.RandomState(0).permutation([1, 4, 9, 12, 15])
array([ 9,  1,  4, 12, 15])
>>> np.random.RandomState(0).permutation([1, 4, 9, 12, 15])
array([ 9,  1,  4, 12, 15])
>>> np.random.RandomState(0).permutation([1, 4, 9, 12, 15])
array([ 9,  1,  4, 12, 15])
>>> np.random.RandomState(100).permutation([1, 4, 9, 12, 15])
array([ 4,  9, 12, 15,  1])
>>> np.random.RandomState(100).permutation([1, 4, 9, 12, 15])
array([ 4,  9, 12, 15,  1])
>>> np.random.RandomState(100).permutation([1, 4, 9, 12, 15])
array([ 4,  9, 12, 15,  1])
```