# Replacing -999 with a number but I want all replaced number to be different

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame named `df` and in `df['salary']` column, there are 400 values represented by same number `-999`. I want to replace that `-999` value with any number in between `200` and `500`. I want to replace all 400 values with a different number from 200 to 500. So far I have written this code:

```
df['salary'] = df['salary'].replace(-999, random.randint(200, 500))
```

but this code is replacing all -999 with the same value. I want all replaced values to be different from each other. How can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Series.mask` with `np.random.randint`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"salary":[0,1,2,3,4,5,-999,-999,-999,1,3,5,-999]})

df['salary'] = df["salary"].mask(df["salary"].eq(-999), np.random.randint(200, 500, size=len(df)))

print (df)

    salary
0        0
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6      413
7      497
8      234
9        1
10       3
11       5
12     341
```

If you want non-repeating numbers instead:

```
s = pd.Series(range(200, 500)).sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)

df['salary'] = df["salary"].mask(df["salary"].eq(-999), s)
```

Comment: are you sure ```np.random.randint``` does not repeat numbers?

Comment: I just re-read his Q and you might be right, added in the above.

Comment: `np.random.randint(200, 500, size=len(df)))` is replacing -999 values with different value everytime. How can I apply random_state in it ?

Comment: See [`np.random.seed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do).