# Set up Numpy random seed to 150 to make sure you get the same results

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to add Numpy Random seed to 150 to get the same results.

I tried

```
simulations = np.random.seed(simulations)
```

But got me a float error

```
# Generate sales samples 
simulations = 10000
sales_sims = np.random.normal(sales_mean, sales_std, simulations)

print(sales_sims)
print("mean:", np.mean(sales_sims))
print("std:", np.std(sales_sims))
```

My question: How to set up Numpy random seed to my 10,000 simulations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a guide on setting the random state for numpy. [What does numpy.random.seed(0) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494489/what-does-numpy-random-seed0-do)

```
np.random.seed(150) #set seed
sales_mean = 0 # replace with desired value
sales_std = 1 # replace with desired value

#Generate sales samples 
simulations = 10000
sales_sims = np.random.normal(sales_mean, sales_std, simulations)
print(sales_sims)
print("mean:", np.mean(sales_sims))
print("std:", np.std(sales_sims))
```

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Fair point. I’ll modify my answer.