# Difference between Numpy's random module and Python?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, python-module

If a project is importing Numpy, what are the advantages in using Numpy's random versus Python's?

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Comment: see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029993/differences-between-numpy-random-and-random-random-in-python)

Comment: `numpy.random` is designed to work with and return `numpy.ndarray`s. if you are using `numpy` the it is the natural choice