# Fastest way to get a random number between 1 and 1million in python

Tags: python, numpy, random

What is the absolute fastest way of achieving this? I will be doing this over 1 million times per day so I want maximum efficiency.

With numpy (avg after 20 runs 0.0001679009692429128)

```
t0 = time.clock()
print(np.random.randint(1,1000000))
t1 = time.clock()
print (t1-t0)
```

With random (avg: 0.0000920492372555262)

```
t2 = time.clock()
print(random.choice(range(1,1000000)))
t3 = time.clock()
print (t3-t2)
```

To my surprise random was consistently faster than numpy. Is there a faster way?

Comment: One million times per day is a very small amount for a computer.  The method doesn't matter too much here.

Comment: why don't you generate 1 million numbers once and just read from it when you need to.

Comment: The time to print overwhelms the time to generate a random number by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Calling `random.choices(range(1,1000000), k=1000000)` takes about half a second. If you have to do that once a day it really should not be an issue

Comment: "I want maximum efficiency" -- you probably spent more time writing your timing tests and composing this question than your CPU will spend generating a million numbers a day, even if your program runs every day for the rest of your life. Premature optimization is not an efficient use of programmer time.

Answer (score 3):

`numpy` is more efficient when generating large samples (arrays) of random numbers. For example,

```
In [10]: %timeit np.random.randint(1,1000000, 1000000)
5.14 ms ± 64.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [11]: %timeit [random.choice(range(1,1000000)) for _ in range(1000000)]
1.01 s ± 14.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

In addition, see [How can I time a code segment for testing performance with Pythons timeit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2866380/8033585) on how to perform timing tests. When you use `time.clock()`, you should at least try to repeat the operation multiple times and then compute mean time. It is more advisable to use `timeit` for timing tests. Also, as others have mentioned in the comments, `print()` takes significantly longer that random number generation, so your timing test is mostly measuring how fast `print()` works. Instead, you should do something like this:

```
In [12]: repeat = 1000000
    ...: t0 = time.clock()
    ...: for _ in range(repeat):
    ...:     np.random.randint(1, 1000000)
    ...: t1 = time.clock()
    ...: print((t1 - t0) / repeat)
1.3564629999999908e-06

In [13]: repeat = 1000000
    ...: t2 = time.clock()
    ...: for _ in range(repeat):
    ...:     random.choice(range(1, 1000000))
    ...: t3 = time.clock()
    ...: print((t3 - t2) / repeat)
1.0206699999999956e-06
```

So, for a single number, `numpy` is on average just about 35% slower than built-in random number generator. However, previous tests show that when generating large samples, `numpy` is significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a test program. It showed that it only cost 1 second to complete your task. So just write whatever way you want, it will not be your bottleneck.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Xiang Wang @ 2018-05-23 16:49:00

import time
import random

start = time.time()

for i in range(1000000):
    random.randint(1, 1000000)

end = time.time()

print("total time: {}".format(end-start))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using numpy, it is more efficient to generate all the values you need at once with [`random.random_integers`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html#numpy.random.random_integers). Both python and numpy use Mersenne Twister. More info: [Differences between numpy.random and random.random in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029993/differences-between-numpy-random-and-random-random-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`random.getrandbits` seems to be much faster than other `random` module tools.

```
%timeit random.randint(0,1000000)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
799 ns ± 2.45 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit random.choice(range(0,1000000))                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
742 ns ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit random.getrandbits(20)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
83.9 ns ± 1.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Read this for further information:
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/slow-and-fast-methods-for-generating-random-integers-in-python/