# Unique seed acrossing multiple imported files with random module (python)

Tags: python, random-seed

I have a big simulation where I set a seed value (through the random.seed) for the random module in  the main file. The main file imports the random module and other files, which import random module too. When I run the simulation, I hope the setted seed is shared to imported files, but as imported files are executed first than main file, the random module in that files reset the seed every time. Below, a reproducible example.

File main.py:

```
# main.py

import foo 
import random

random.seed (10)
main = random.randint(1, 100)
print("main: ", main)
```

File foo.py:

```
# foo.py

import random

foo = random.randint(1, 100)
print("foo:  ", foo)
```

When I execute `python main.py` multiple times the value of the `main` variable is always the same, as I expected. But the value of `foo` variable changes every time. How can I can set the seed in the main file such that same seed will be used in imported files?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846128/how-to-set-global-random-seed-in-python though there's no solution given there.

Answer (score 3):

I looked at [the source code for `random`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/random.py#L846-L851). Each time you import `random` it creates a new instance of a class called `Random` with a new seed. This means that what you want to do is not possible, unfortunately, unless you pass around the random number generator directly.

One of the ways you could do this is:

```py
import random
random.seed(123)
import foo
foo.random = random
```

though that won't affect any code that's executed when `foo` is loaded, only functions in `foo` called after the replacement `foo.random = random`. It also won't propagate to any `import`s done by `foo`.

Another way would be defining a helper file or function that sets up `random` for you, and using that throughout your codebase — though again that won't affect any library functions that rely on `random` directly.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I get the seed from user input and process it before set it.

Comment: So it is not possible to define a global seed for a Python repository with multiple files in an easy manner?

Comment: not if you want to use the standard library's `random` module.