# how to random 10 numbers between 1 and 5 in list and the list must inculde all number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

```
from random import randint
k=[]
for i in range(10):
    k.append(randint(1,5))
    k.sort()
print(k)
```

The output will be correct but sometimes it not include value from 1 to 5. for example, maybe k=[2,3,3,3,3,4,4,5,5,5] and not included 1. I need to include all numbers

Comment: why do you sort 10 times?

Comment: @PatrickArtner my mistake , but I need to re randint if the list doesn't included 1,2,3,4,5 in their list. Must I use while loop ? or what

Comment: Take the range(1, 6) add random numbers from this range, then create a random permutation of the results so the initial constant numbers are in random places and not all at the beginning. Or select a random number between 1...n-4 and take that many 1s, then a random number between 1...n-4-k, where k is sum of items taken so far for each next number, then randomize the order (random permutation). See if you can code this yourself, if not let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 random numbers between 1 and 5 means a list of `[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]` is a valid result - it is just very unlikely.

If you need to ensure 1 to 5 are in it, start with `[1,2,3,4,5]` and add 5 random numbers:

```
from random import choices

k = [1,2,3,4,5]
k.extend( choices(range(1,6), k=5)) # add 5 more random numbers
k.sort()

print(k)
```

to get

```
[1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,5]  # etc.
```

The part `choices(range(1,6), k=5)`  returns a list of 5 numbers in the range 1-5 without need for a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using [**NumPy** library could have priority over pythonic random](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57222029/13394817) to work with to do so; which may be [very faster in huge data volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838531/13394817):

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.arange(1, 6)                        # create integer numbers from 1 to (6 - 1) to ensure 1 to 5 will be contained
ran = np.random.random_integers(1, 6, 5)      # create 5 random integers from 1 to (6 - 1)
combine = np.concatenate((nums, ran))         # combining aforementioned two arrays together
np.random.shuffle(combine)                    # shuffling the created combined array
```

which will get arrays like `[4 5 4 2 5 1 3 4 2 1]`, which will contain all integers from 1 to 5. This array can be converted to list by `combine.tolist()`.