# Failure to reproduce scikit-learn and numpy dependent code when multiprocessing is used

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, reproducible-research

The code below is completely reproducible when `n_jobs=1` at `cross_validate` function, but not so when `n_jobs=-1` or `2`.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate,RepeatedStratifiedKFold

class DecisionTree(DecisionTreeClassifier):
    def fit(self,X,Y):
        weight = np.random.uniform(size=Y.shape)
        return super().fit(X,Y,sample_weight=weight)

def main():
    X,Y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
    rks = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_repeats=2,n_splits=5,random_state=42)
    clf = DecisionTree(random_state=42)
    res = cross_validate(clf,X,Y,cv=rks,n_jobs=2)['test_score']*100
    return res.mean(),res.std()

if __name__=='__main__':
    np.random.seed(42)
    print(main())
```

Please note the `np.random.uniform` call at `fit` function. The code is also completely reproducible without such numpy calls. It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7030595/4553309) that `numpy.random.seed` is not thread-safe. But I saw no mention of this in sklearn's [FAQ](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-set-a-random-state-for-an-entire-execution), according to which providing `random_state` everywhere should suffice.

Is there anyway to use both numpy random calls and multiprocessing in sklearn while maintaining full reproducibility?

EDIT: I think it reproduces fine if we put `n_jobs>1` inside estimators that take it, while instantiating `RandomForestClassifier` for example.

Comment: how is `multiprocessing` spawning processes?  (if you're not doing anything then this is [OS dependent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods)).  also if `sklearn` happens to use anything from the system `random` then that will get reseeded in new processes by `multiprocessing`

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9650 might be relevant as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would appear your `DecisionTree` class should be using the `random_state` that was passed in.  I get consistent results when do:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state

class DecisionTree(DecisionTreeClassifier):
    def fit(self, X, Y):
        rng = check_random_state(self.random_state)
        weight = rng.uniform(size=Y.shape)
        return super().fit(X, Y, sample_weight=weight)
```

but otherwise do as you do.  note that with this change you can also remove the call to `np.random.seed(42)` as the RNG state is explicitly set everywhere it needs to be