# Randomiser not working

Tags: python

So I am using python to create a text based pokemon game. However a bug keeps popping up, where the enemy does two attacks in one turn, which are the same every time, even if though they should be random.
*Apologies for the layout*

**CODE**

```
import math, random
print("-------------POKEMON BROWN-------------")
print("welcome to pokemon brown")
print("choose a pokemon")
print("Charmander, Squirtle, Bulbasaur")
pokemon_1 = input()
pokemon_1 = (pokemon_1.lower())

print("ahh " + pokemon_1 + " a good choice")

enemy = 1

print("Ok lets battle!")

battle = 1
hp = 20
mp = 10
enemyhp = 20
enemymp = 10
print("----Battle Start----")
print("")
battle = 1
while True:
    turn = 1
    player_turn = 1
    if(pokemon_1 == "squirtle"):
        player_turn = 1
        print("----Your turn----")
        print("")
        print("Pokemon:" + pokemon_1 + "/HP = " + str(hp) + "/MP = " + str(mp))
        print("Tackle(1 DMG), Tail Whip(2 DMG, 2MP), Water Gun(5 DMG, 10 MP), Back")
        move = input()
        move = (move.lower())
        if(move == "tackle"):
            print("Your Squirtle uses tackle and deals 1 DMG")
            enemyhp -= 1
            turn = 1
        if(move == "tail whip"):
            if(mp >= 2):
                print("Your Squirtle uses tail whip and deals 2 DMG")
                enemyhp -= 2
                mp -= 2
                turn = 1
            else:
                print("not enough MP")

        if (move == "water gun"):
            if(mp >= 10):
                print("Your Squirtle uses water gun and deals 5 DMG")
                enemyhp -= 5
                mp -= 10
                turn = 1
            else:
                print("not enough MP")

    if(pokemon_1 == "charmander"):
        player_turn = 1
        print("")
        print("----Your turn----")    
        print("Pokemon: " + pokemon_1 + "/HP = " + str(hp) + "/MP = " + str(mp))
        print("Scratch(2 DMG), Ember(4 DMG, 5MP), Back")
        move = input()
        move = (move.lower())
        if(move == "scratch"):
            print("Your Charmander uses scratch and deals 2 DMG")
            enemyhp -= 2
            turn = 1
        if(move == "ember"):
            if(mp >= 2):
                print("Your Charmander uses Ember and deals 4 DMG")
                enemyhp -= 4
                mp -= 5
                turn = 1
            else:
                print("not enough MP")

    if(pokemon_1 == "bulbasaur"):
        player_turn = 1
        print("")
        print("----Your turn----")

        print("Pokemon: " + pokemon_1 + "/HP = " + str(hp) + "/MP = " + str(mp))
        print("Tackle(1 DMG), Vine whip(5 DMG, 5MP)")
        move = input()
        move = (move.lower())
        if(move == "scratch"):
            print("Your Bulbasuar uses Tackle and deals 2 DMG")
            enemyhp -= 2
            turn = 1
        if(move == "tail whip"):
            if(mp >= 2):
                print("Your Bulbasaur uses Vine Whip and deals 5 DMG")
                enemyhp -= 4
                mp -= 5
                turn = 1
            else:
                print("not enough MP")

    if(turn == 1):
        if(enemy == 1):
            print("")
            print("----Enemy's turn----")
            print("Enemy Pokemon: Squirtle / HP = " + str(enemyhp) + " / MP = " + str(enemymp))


            if(enemymp == 10):
                enemy_move = random.randint(1,6)

            if(enemymp < 10 and enemymp >= 2):
                enemy_move = random.randint(1,5)

            if(enemymp < 2):
                enemy_move = 0

            if(enemy_move == 1 or 2 or 3):
                print("Enemy Squirtle uses tackle and deals 1 DMG")
                hp -= 1
                turn = 0
            if(enemy_move == 4 or 5):
                if(mp >= 2):
                    print("Enemy Squirtle uses tail whip and deals 2 DMG")
                    hp -= 2
                    enemymp -= 2
                    turn = 0
                else:
                    print("not enough MP")

            if (enemy_move == 6):
                if(mp >= 10):
                    print("Enemy Squirtle uses water gun and deals 5 DMG")
                    hp -= 5
                    enemymp -= 10
                    turn = 0
                else:
                    print("not enough MP")
```

**SHELL**

```
-------------POKEMON BROWN-------------
welcome to pokemon brown
choose a pokemon
Charmander, Squirtle, Bulbasaur
charmander
ahh charmander a good choice
Ok lets battle!
----Battle Start----


----Your turn----
Pokemon: charmander/HP = 20/MP = 10
Scratch(2 DMG), Ember(4 DMG, 5MP), Back
scratch
Your Charmander uses scratch and deals 2 DMG

----Enemy's turn----
Enemy Pokemon: Squirtle / HP = 18 / MP = 10
Enemy Squirtle uses tackle and deals 1 DMG
Enemy Squirtle uses tail whip and deals 2 DMG

----Your turn----
Pokemon: charmander/HP = 17/MP = 10
Scratch(2 DMG), Ember(4 DMG, 5MP), Back
```

Comment: [you should seed your random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that you are not using `or` correctly.

```
if(enemy_move == 1 or 2 or 3):
if(enemy_move == 4 or 5):
```

Will evaluate to `True` every time. This is because logically 0 has a boolean value of `False` and any other number has a value of `True`

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(1)
True
```

So your condition ends up as.

```
if (enemy_move == 1 or True or True):
```

To work correctly you need to compare each value.

```
if(enemy_move == 1 or enemy_move == 2 or enemy_move == 3)
```

This can be cleaned up various ways such as.

```
if enemy_move in (1, 2, 3):
if 1 <= enemy_move <= 3:
```

Now, your other issues include having multiple `if` statements, now unless you want to check each one every time you should use `if/elif`

```
if enemy_move in (1, 2, 3):
    ...
elif enemy_move in (4, 5):
    ...
elif enemy_move == 6:
   ...
else:
   ...
```

This will then check each one in order from first to last, if one evaluates to `False` then it will move on to the next, once the condition is met, `True`. Then it won't do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(enemy_move == 1 or 2 or 3):
```

This checks if `enemy_move` is equal to 1, and if that evaluates to false, it checks if `2` is a true value, which it always is. To check if the value is any of the three you need three comparisons, or you can use `in`:

```
if enemy_move in (1, 2, 3):
```

Or you could use a double sided range check:

```
if 1 <= enemy_move < 4:
```

This is python, so you don't need to put parentheses around the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

during an if statement like :

```
...
            if(enemy_move == 1 or 2 or 3):
...
            if(enemy_move == 4 or 5):
...
            if (enemy_move == 6):
...
```

Notice that only the first two will always execute together, because when the if evaluates, it checks [if enemy_move equals to 1] or if [2] or [3], the 2 and 3 should be enemy_move == 2 and enemy_move == 3 , if you don't put 'enemy_move ==' it would always evaluate as TRUE with if operator, which is why only the last 
    ...
                if (enemy_move == 6):
    ...
Don't get executed together.

Answer (score 0):

when you use random, you should always use a unique seed, otherwise the generated numbers will always be the same

set your seed once when you start your program like so

```
random.seed( ... )
```

what seed you use is not really important, as long as it changes. Best example most people use is the current timestamp.

```
time.time()
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is with the if statements
Do NOT do this with if statements:

```
if (enemy_move == 2 or 3 or 4):
```

What you want to do is the following:

```
if (enemy_move == 2 or enemy_move == 3 or enemy_move =-- 4)
```