# Why tensorflow random_normal function gives different outputs with a fixed seed value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I set fixed a seed value and run the session using following line of codes.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    matrix = tf.random_normal([2,2], mean=1, stddev=1, seed=1)
    print(matrix.eval())
    print(matrix.eval())
    print(matrix.eval())
    print(sess.run(matrix))
    print(sess.run(matrix))
    print(sess.run(matrix))
    print(sess.run(matrix))
```

But the code gave me the output like this,

```
[[1.2818339 3.3878284]
 [3.2804048 0.691338 ]]
[[0.84588486 1.3642604 ]
 [1.6235023  0.96976113]]
[[2.3133767 2.4734092]
 [1.6430309 0.7378005]]
[[ 1.8944461   0.39336425]
 [ 0.1861412  -0.01721728]]
[[-0.6642921   2.3849297 ]
 [-0.06870818 -0.1625154 ]]
[[ 1.0668459   0.45170426]
 [ 2.4276698  -0.24925494]]
[[1.8668368  1.3444978 ]
 [1.5144594  0.31290668]]
```

I expect to print exact values because i fixed the seed value. Why does it print out a different values?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each run, your computational graph is evaluated anew, thereby generating new random numbers, but not resetting the seed.

I think running the entire Python file again should give the same output as before.

Comment: This is how random seeds work in general... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do

Answer (score 1):

Seed is used only for initializing the `matrix`. Every time you run the `session` the matrix will be initialized with the same values.

However, every time you call `matrix.eval()` it will give you the next random value in the chain of random values.

If you wanted always the same number you would have to do the following although I doubt its usefulness.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
   matrix = tf.random_normal([2,2], mean=1, stddev=1, seed=1)
   print(matrix.eval())
   matrix = tf.random_normal([2,2], mean=1, stddev=1, seed=1)
   print(matrix.eval())
```

Returns:

```
[[ 1.28183389  3.38782835]
[ 3.28040481  0.691338  ]]
[[ 1.28183389  3.38782835]
[ 3.28040481  0.691338  ]]
```

Comment: I'm building a network but I don't know if it's performing well because every time it trains I get different results. How can I be certain? I'm defining my weights as `'weights': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([22, n_nodes_hl1], seed=1))`