# How to create np array random data on age vs time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

How to create np array random data on age vs time?

My aim is to create a scatter plot representing random data on age vs. time spent watching TV.

```
from pylab import randn

X = randn(500)
Y = randn(500)
plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

I want age between 18 and 50 and time between 0 to 24 hours

Comment: What did you try? what did work/not work? Please improve your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
import random
import numpy as np
age=np.array(random.sample(list(range(18,51)),10))
time=np.array(random.sample(list(range(0,24)),10))
```

`random.sample` takes a list of elements as first argument and the number of samples you want as the second argument.

That gives :

```
age  : [47 45 37 19 23 34 39 24 32 42]
time : [18 12 13  1 15 21 23 22  3 17]
```

On plotting it :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(age, time)
plt.show()
```

[image]

To recreate the same random numbers every time you run it, you can use [`random.seed()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 2):

It's super easy with [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html). You can use numpy library to do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

age = np.random.randint(18, 50, 20)
time = np.random.randint(0, 24, 20)

plt.scatter(age, time)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Column-wise multiplication in numpy

You can easily create custom-sized random arrays with numpy with the commands `numpy.random.rand(d0, d1, …, dn)` for uniform distributions or `numpy.random.randn(d0, d1, …, dn)` for normal distributions, where `dn` is the number of samples in the nth dimension. In your case you'll have `d0=500` and `d1=2`.

However the values will be sampled from the interval [0, 1) in `numpy.random.rand(d0, d1, …, dn)`. Or the standard normal distribution for `numpy.random.randn(d0, d1, …, dn)` (i.e. mean = 0 and variance = 1).

A nice turnaround for this is to sum and multiply the arrays column-wise to shilft the distributions to the desired values. To multiply in a column-wise fashion an array `arr` with a vector `vec` you can use this small snippet of code `arr.dot(np.diag(vec))`. Be careful, `vec` should have as much elements as `arr` has columns.

This snippet works by turning `vec` into a diagonal matrix (i.e. a matrix where everything is zero except the main diagonal) and the multiplying `arr` to the diagonal matrix.

### For uniform distributions

Remeber that to turn a sample `x` from an uniform distribution `[0, 1)` to `[min, max)`, you do `new_x = (max - min) * x + min`. So if you want an uniform distribution and you know the max and min limits for boths variables, you can do as use the following code:

```
import numpy as np

n_samples = 500
max_age, min_age = 80, 10
max_hours, min_hours = 10, 0

array = np.random.rand(n_samples, 2)  #returns samples from the uniform distribution
range_vector = np.array([max_age - min_age, max_hours - min_hours])
min_vector = np.array([min_age, min_hours])

sample = array.dot(np.diag(range_vector)) + np.ones(array.shape).dot(np.diag(min_vector))
```

### Normal distributions

If you want a normal distribution and you know the mean and variances of both columns use the following code. Remeber that to shift a sample `x` from an standard normal distribution to a distribution with a different mean and standard deviation, you go `new_x = deviation * x + mean`.

```
import numpy as np

n_samples = 500
mean_age, deviation_age = 40, 20
mean_hours, deviation_hours = 5, 2

array = np.random.rand(n_samples, 2)  #returns samples from the standard normal distribution
deviation_vector = np.array([deviation_age, deviation_hours])
mean_vector = np.array([mean_age, mean_hours])

sample = array.dot(np.diag(deviation_vector)) + np.ones(array.shape).dot(np.diag(mean_vector))
```

Be careful however, with the normal distributions you can end up withg negative values.

You can also have a look at all the documentation numpy has on random variables: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html

Finally please notice that column-wise multiplication only works when you want both samples to be independant.