# Generate random looking numbers deterministically from a random-access lookup key in O(1) space and time

Tags: random

I want to output random looking numbers based on an input. If the same input is put in, the same output is given.

I don't want to pregenerate and store a bunch of random data, and I don't want it to take an O(n) amount of time to recover the nth index.

It does *not* need to be secure, cryptographically or otherwise, just enough to look random.

Comment: Where/how would you like these stored would a database work?

Comment: Why store gigs of random numbers as opposed to return the next random number?

Comment: Well exactly I don't want to store the whole array, just returns sections of it on request.

Comment: You would need to store the whole array somewhere to be able to give sections of it unless you want to just give a next newly generated section

Comment: You can seed the random number generator with, say, the current ticks of `Now` thereby creating relative randomness and generating + returning *n* consecutive random numbers.

Comment: Why would I need to "store the whole array somewhere"?  If it's generated algorithmically using an LCG then there is presumably a way to return any request at [offset, offset+size-1], I just don't want to have to iterate from 0 thru offset to do that.

Comment: Do you want to be able to read the same section more than once?

Comment: Yes, and to read the same data back each time.

Comment: If you want random access, deterministic, jumbled-looking data, then I suggest using a hash function instead of storing anything.

Comment: Would that hash the array index? [edited]

Comment: How big do you want the "sections" to be?

Comment: What determines what "section" you want; is the size of the "section" dynamic? For example, can I get 10 from a section, then 20 where the first 10 are the same?

Comment: Any size of read from a few bytes to the whole array.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3 has a variable output length so you could specify dynamically how long you want your "random" data to be. Just use the index as the input data and it'll be deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a deterministic random-access function from an (index,length) pair to a random looking string of bytes you could use `SHA3-N(index)[:length]` where N is the first convenient number greater than length.

This would not behave identically to an actual array as reading indexes 1 (with length 10) and 5 (with length 10) would not have any overlap (which you'd expect from an array).

This is going to be slow and very inconvenient for N>512, so if you need longer strings you'll want to do multiple rounds. Something like SHA3-512(SHA3-512(index)[0:256])++SHA3-512(SHA3-512(index)[256:512]) to get something 1024bytes long.

Armed with the multiple rounds part you could use any hash function (e.g. SHA256, MD5) which might be more convenient.

I should note that this is definitely not secure and the output could easily be predicted by an adversary.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a random number generator will [generate the same sequence of pseudo-random numbers given the same seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do/22639752#22639752). For example, such python code might be like so:

```
random.seed(1)
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(random.randint(1,100)
```

Will print the same list no matter how many times you invoke that code. Similarly, so will this:

```
random.seed(42)
for i in range(1, 10):
    print(random.randint(1,100)
```

If somehow you then describe the sections of your array as a seed (you could use a hash function to do this indeed) you can seed the generator with that value and reliably allow dynamic sizing of the list requested.