# Discrete event_random number generation

Tags: python-3.x

System: Simulating Discrete events for 100 steps with number of events 10; I am using Spyder(Python 3.6); New to python!

Question: Can I generate different random numbers for each step in my loop? 
I need my random number between (0,1) and for each step, random number should be dynamically generated. I "don't" want random numbers to be repeated.

I am using the command; 
import numpy as np
r = np.random.rand()

Any help regarding this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [random.seed(): What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 0):

You need to seed a pseudo-random number generator. Here is a link to another Stack Overflow question that contains your answer:

[random.seed(): What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do)

Comment: No, my question is to generate different random number for each run in my program. However, the number generated for previous run is being stored and regenerated for the next run.