# TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType) for time.sleep

Tags: python

I have been trying this code to get a random seed, but it always fails.

```
    import string
import random
import time
import sys
from random import seed
possibleCharacters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase + ' .,!?;:'

target = input("Enter text: ")
attemptThis = ''.join(random.choice(possibleCharacters) for i in range(len(target)))
attemptNext = ''

completed = False

generation = 0

while completed == False:
    print(attemptThis)
    attemptNext = ''
    completed = True
    for i in range(len(target)):
        if attemptThis[i] != target[i]:
            completed = False
            attemptNext += random.choice(possibleCharacters)
        else:
            attemptNext += target[i]
    generation += 1
    attemptThis = attemptNext
    time.sleep(0)

time.sleep(seed(1))    

print("Operation completed in " + str(generation) + " different generations!")
```

The error is always as this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "N:\ict python\python programs\demo\genration text.py", line 30, in <module>
    time.sleep(seed(1))
TypeError: an integer is required (got type NoneType) at the end of it.
```

I have tried other functions - randint, pi and generating a random number and deciding by a random number.

Do I have to hardcode that number, or is there a way to make it generate a random delay?

Comment: `seed(1)` return None what do you want?

Comment: you can read about the `seed` here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31683870/8060120

Answer (score 3):

The `random.seed()` function always returns `None` but `time.sleep()` needs a number (the number of seconds to sleep).

try `random.randint()` instead to generate a random integer:

```
import random
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 50))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use also `random.randint(a, b)` function - to generate random integer number. `seed` function just initializes random numbers generator.

Answer (score 1):

The type of seed is None and the time.sleep() expects an integer.
To send a random integer as a parameter for sleep you can try:

```
time.sleep(random.randint(1, 60))
```

You need to import randim libraby for this.