# Permanently set seed in python

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I have read several questions including those aimed specifically at `numpy`. I am however simply interested in permanently setting `seed` in(with) `random` and hence generate the same random `float` with `random.random()` with each call. Here's what I did:

```
import random
random.seed(2)
```

First call:

```
random.random()
0.9560342718892494
```

Second call:

```
random.random()
0.9478274870593494
```

I could keep calling `random.seed` but would appreciate if someone could explain what is going on or what exactly I can do to set `seed` once and generate the same random float with each `random.random()` call.

I am currently trying to learn `python` so my apologies if this is very basic and already has an answer. I have read several questions before posting.

Comment: You can set your seed as a environment variable and import it, or set it as a class attribute

Comment: Do you want to get the _same_ number for every call to `random()`? That's not very random. If you just want one random number then assign the random number to some variable and reuse that variable.

Comment: I need to return `0.9560342718892494` at each call. My perhaps naive understanding of `seed` is that it should aid "reproducibility."

Comment: `seed()` initializes the random number generator, so every subsequent calls to `random()` produce same sequence of values based on this seed. Not that `random()` will return exact same value each call

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. So `0.9560342718892494` is the first value in this sequence. Don't know if I should delete the question.

Comment: @NelsonGon You can answer it for yourself and then close it.

Comment: I would say answer and leave it. Someone else might have the same initial misunderstanding and find this useful.

Comment: Random depends on seed and time. So ask for random with same seed and diferent time will return 2 diferents results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [random.seed(): What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do)

Comment: @Wonka how does it depend on `time`? (it obviously depends on the number of iterations, but that is not *time*. `python3 -c "import random; random.seed(2); print(random.random())"` still returns `0.9560342718892494 `, even though 4 years have passed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @Andrej Kesely and @buzjwa , setting `seed` does not guarantee that you will get the same value at each call. What is really going on is that we set a random state that then determines the sequence of random floats generated.

When we call `random.random()` the first time, what we are really doing is initiate the process of random number generation and return the first value in this sequence of numbers.

That is once we set `random.seed(2)`, each time we follow this with a `random.random()` call, we return `0.9560342718892494` which is the first value in this sequence of numbers. Subsequent `random.random()` calls, return the next values in the sequence as per the corresponding call number.