# What exactly is a PRNG seed and how does it work in c++?

Tags: c++

From what I’ve read on the c++ website, the srand function, puts a seed in the rand function, but I don’t really understand what a seed is.

Comment: I would have a start with your research [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator)

Comment: Run a Google search for "pseudo-random number generation", and you should find plenty of information.

Comment: Also, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed).

Comment: What is "the c++ website"?  It may be explained on the website you're looking at.

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do

Comment: @DrewDormann Should we add it to the dupe list?

Comment: I found a better dupe that answers this question exactly.

Comment: @NathanOliver yours is C, mine is Python... I suppose so.

Comment: There, now it has all the targets :)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Not really; that question is about how `rand()` "knows" what the seed is when there's no connection [at the callsite] between `rand()` and `srand()` and thus no evident transfer of state (obvs it's a global somewhere). This one is just... what is a seed

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *"but I don’t really understand what a seed is."*

Comment: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). You *really* should consider using the modern facilities in the [<random>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header.

Comment: I really don't get the down votes. Sure, it's not a *great* question, but it's a fair enough question; "what's a seed in the context of a PRNG". And it's quite answerable.

Comment: @Ayxan Exactly.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Lack of research evidence is quite, well, evident

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes it is. No argument there. But it's still answerable (see my proposed answer for example) and I think it makes more sense to answer it than close it. This is not the first, nor last, newbie to be confused about what a PRNG seed is. So we may as well have an answer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Nobody's talking about answering or closing. We're talking about downvoting. If you hover over the downvote button you'll see the answer to your _"I really don't get the down votes"_. As for answering, yes of course it _can_ be answered; the bigger question is whether it _should_ be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I don’t really understand what a seed is" - A *seed* in the context of a Pseudo Random Number Generator (PRNG) is a starting value to use for the generation of the pseudo random sequence.

A PRNG that starts with the same seed will (in most cases) produce the same sequence of random numbers. This is great for replayability of a scenario, but is not generally what you want in production. Usually you want to provide a unique/unpredictable seed to the generator for each instance of the application, so that each run gives a unique stream of pseudo random numbers.

I would recommend using the new random facilities (since C++11) that are available in the [random](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) header over `srand()`/`rand()` since `rand` has a very low range and usually also a very low period. The new facilities are *much* better.

You may also find this talk enlightening: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

The [Wikipedia page on pseudo random number generators](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) is also worth a read.