# Why does the Python random.random() give a different value if the previously generated value is explicitly set as the new seed?

Tags: python, random, random-seed

I have read that the `random` module in Python uses the previously generated value as the seed except for the first time where it uses the system time.
(https://stackoverflow.com/a/22639752/11455105,  https://pynative.com/python-random-seed/)
If this is true, why don't I get the same value when I explicitly set the previously generated value as the new seed like this:

```
random.seed(random.randint(1, 100))
```

The same doesn't work for the `random.random()` method either.

```py
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(20)
>>> random.randint(1,100)
93
>>> random.randint(1,100)
88
>>> random.seed(20)
>>> random.randint(1,100)
93
>>> random.randint(1,100)
88
>>> random.seed(20)
>>> random.seed(random.randint(1,100))
>>> random.randint(1,100)
64
```

Why didn't the last `randint()` call not give 88?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It's not true. Seeding will initialize some inner state. The inner state always deterministically implies the next random-number. But seeding with some integer x does not mean setting the inner-state like it would look like outputting number x. (the internal state of the MersenneTwister is bigger than some integer. Or else your period would never exceed 2^int-size)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because what you read was false, or you misunderstood what it said.  CPython uses the Mersenne Twister generator under the covers, which has a state consuming 19937 bits.  What you pass to `.seed()` is *not* the new state, but merely a pile of bits which is expanded to a full 19937-bit state via an undocumented (implementation-dependent) algorithm.

Note:  if you want to save and restore states, that's what the `.getstate()` and `.setstate()` methods are for.

Answer (score 5):

Python `random` module **does not use** the previously generated value as the seed. However, Python uses the [Mersenne Twister](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) generator to create pseudo-randomness. This algorithm is [deterministic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_algorithm): that implies that it next state (the next generated number) depends on the previous one. This is different from the [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) which is a value used to configure the initial state of the generator.