# Random password generator function in Python

Tags: python, string, random

I need to create a function that generates a random password of length n, and seed s. So far i have the following:

```
def ran_password(n,s):
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(n))
```

This creates the random password as required, but I'm not sure how to incorporate the seed within my function?

Such that when i run the function ran_password(10,123) it always prints out the same password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [random.seed(): What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `random.seed()` function.

```
def ran_password(n,s):
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase
    random.seed(s)
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for x in range(n))
```