# How to generate a true random number from mouse movement?

Tags: python, user-interface, random, mouseevent, trng

How to create a python program that lets users move the mouse anywhere on the screen and generate a random number based on those movements. I am trying to implement [this feature](http://www.russellcottrell.com/mousePointerRNG.htm)

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is not a coding service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @alec_djinn I just wanted a guideline as to how to implement it and what is the logic behind it

Comment: If you want truly random numbers, use `random.SystemRandom`, eg `rng = random.SystemRandom(); x = rng.randint(1, 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel - random.random does a good job in generating random numbers. You just need to re-seed it before each random call. Below, a complex number that represents the mouse position is used as a seed. Of course, the same mouse position will generate the same number.

```
import pyautogui
import random as r

def rnd_mouse():
    pos = pyautogui.position()
    sd = pos[0]+1j*pos[1]
    r.seed(sd)
    return r.random()


print(rnd_mouse())
```

Output:

```
 0.25073497760281793
```

Comment: what is the purpose of r.seed() and seed() function in general.Also, will it be true random like the website I mentioned.Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do
These will be truly random as long as you don't click on the same spot.

Comment: can you tell me why did you use 1j*pos[1] here. I read it is for imaginary numbers. Thanks

Comment: The x-axis is real, the y-axis is imaginary (1j*pos[1]). This way, both axes of your mouse position are used in computing the random number.

Comment: Lev B I am confused as to why is the y co-ordinate on a computer screen imaginary can you please guide.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2660523/why-are-complex-numbers-treated-as-coordinates

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:complex/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:complex-plane/a/the-complex-plane

Comment: The real question is that will this number be true random number?