# How do I stop lists added with .append() from updating automatically?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to make a program that generates a certain number of random lists and then places these into another list. This is my code:

```
import random

RandomPassword=["0","0","0"]
PasswordList=[]
for Char in range(0,3):
    RandomPassword[Char]=(random.randint(0,9))
    PasswordList.append(RandomPassword)
print("Password list is", PasswordList)
```

I have used the .append() function to try and do this, but every time I run the program I end up with something like this:

```
Password list is [[4, 8, 1], [4, 8, 1], [4, 8, 1]]
>>>
```

I think it is something to do with the list being a mutable data type, but I'm not sure how to change this. I have trawled the internet and not found anything that I can understand that fixes my problem. I would like to see something like this:

```
Password list is [[3, 6, 7], [4, 8, 6], [2, 5, 4]]
>>>
```

Does anyone have a simple solution?

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: Add `random.seed()` before the line `for ....`, will give different results between runs, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do

Comment: If the object is to return 1 list with 3 numbers, you should change the indentation of the line `PasswordList.append(RandomPassword)`

Comment: @khelwood I have changed the post so that it shows the outcome I want. Hope this makes it easier to understand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a new list inside your loop, like so:

```
import random

PasswordList=[]
for Char in range(0,3):
    RandomPassword=["0","0","0"]
    RandomPassword[Char]=(random.randint(0,9))
    PasswordList.append(RandomPassword)
print("Password list is", PasswordList)
```

Otherwise, you add and modify the same list object three times.

Comment: Thank you! The actual answer involved repeating 'RandomPassword[0]', 'RandomPassword[1]' and so on - a bit clumsy but that was all I needed! Thank you taking the time to help me