# Difference between np.random.seed() and np.random.RandomState()

Tags: python, numpy, random

I know that to seed the randomness of numpy.random, and be able to reproduce it, I should us:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)
```

but what does 
`np.random.RandomState()`
do?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37224116/562769

Comment: Here's a really good discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836335/consistenly-create-same-random-numpy-array/5837352#5837352although you really have to trudge through the comments and note that Robert Kern is a numpy dev

Answer (score 116, accepted):

If you want to set the seed that calls to `np.random...` will use, use `np.random.seed`:

```
np.random.seed(1234)
np.random.uniform(0, 10, 5)
#array([ 1.9151945 ,  6.22108771,  4.37727739,  7.85358584,  7.79975808])
np.random.rand(2,3)
#array([[ 0.27259261,  0.27646426,  0.80187218],
#       [ 0.95813935,  0.87593263,  0.35781727]])
```

Use the class to avoid impacting the global numpy state:

```
r = np.random.RandomState(1234)
r.uniform(0, 10, 5)
#array([ 1.9151945 ,  6.22108771,  4.37727739,  7.85358584,  7.79975808])
```

And it maintains the state just as before:

```
r.rand(2,3)
#array([[ 0.27259261,  0.27646426,  0.80187218],
#       [ 0.95813935,  0.87593263,  0.35781727]])
```

You can see the state of the sort of 'global' class with:

```
np.random.get_state()
```

and of your own class instance with:

```
r.get_state()
```

Comment: Your answer makes sense. But how is the documentation not confusing? `This method is called when RandomState is initialized. It can be called again to re-seed the generator.` It says nothing about the fact that when I call this method, I'm only affecting one global instance (or whatever), and not any of the other `RandomState` instances.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.. the `numpy.random` module documentation should state clearly that the module is initialized with effectively an instance of the `RandomState`. But there isn't any documentation on the module itself at all that I can find.

Answer (score 21):

`np.random.RandomState()` constructs a random number generator. It does not have any effect on the freestanding functions in `np.random`, but must be used explicitly:

```
>>> rng = np.random.RandomState(42)
>>> rng.randn(4)
array([ 0.49671415, -0.1382643 ,  0.64768854,  1.52302986])
>>> rng2 = np.random.RandomState(42)
>>> rng2.randn(4)
array([ 0.49671415, -0.1382643 ,  0.64768854,  1.52302986])
```

Comment: What effect does it have on the freestanding functions?  I thought it created an independent instance as in my answer.

Comment: @askewchan: typo, I meant it does *not* have any effect.

Answer (score 10):

[random.seed](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) is a method to fill [random.RandomState](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) container.

from numpy docs:

```
numpy.random.seed(seed=None)
```

> Seed the generator.
>
> This method is called when RandomState is initialized. It can be called again to re-seed the generator. For details, see RandomState.

```
class numpy.random.RandomState
```

> Container for the Mersenne Twister pseudo-random number generator.

Comment: But if I call RandomState(1234) and create a number with random.uniform() the results are not reproducible. What is a container such as RandomState used for?

Comment: @eran you do realize that [Mersenne twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) and [Uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) are not the same thing? read [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) to know more about what exactly is [random.RandomState](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html), please.

Comment: @eran, actually it is because you are creating another instance of the class.  See my answer to see how to use it.

Comment: Thanks!  I understand it now. Pretty straight forward. The documentation just lacked a proper example.  Or I had a blindspot...

Answer (score 0):

np.random.RandomState() - a class that provides several methods based on different probability distributions.
np.random.RandomState.seed() - called when RandomState() is initialised.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time in answering this question. Can you please give more details about your solution? For example, why is your solution better than the accepted answer? Also, the question was asked and answered 6 years ago. Be sure to look at the date of the original question when answering. Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`Seed` is a global pseudo-random generator. However, `randomstate` is a pseudo-random generator isolated from others, which only impact specific variable.

```py
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
rng.rand(4)
# Out[1]: array([0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318])
rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
rng.rand(4)
# Out[2]: array([0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318])
```

It's basically as same as `Seed`, but as the following, We don't assign randomstate to a variable.

```py
np.random.RandomState(0)
# Out[3]: <mtrand.RandomState at 0xddaa288>
np.random.rand(4)
# Out[4]: array([0.62395295, 0.1156184 , 0.31728548, 0.41482621])
np.random.RandomState(0)
# Out[5]: <mtrand.RandomState at 0xddaac38>
np.random.rand(4)
# Out[6]: array([0.86630916, 0.25045537, 0.48303426, 0.98555979])
```

The latter is different from the former. It means that randomstate only avails inside specific variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth mentioning this description in scikit-learn, ["Controlling randomness"] [1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/common_pitfalls.html#randomness)

and this usage [example in one of the models](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state)