# Difference between RandomState and seed in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have read the documentation but I still find difficult to understand the difference between the use of

```
numpy.random.RandomState(0)
```

or

```
numpy.random.seed(0)
```

Don't they both ensure that the process through which the random values are selected is the same and consistent across runs?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22994423/562769

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`numpy.random.seed(0)` resets the state of the existing global `RandomState` instance that underlies the functions in the `numpy.random` namespace.

`numpy.random.RandomState(0)` returns a new seeded `RandomState` instance but otherwise does not change anything. You have to use the returned `RandomState` instance to get consistent pseudorandom numbers. If you use the functions in the `numpy.random` namespace, you will not get consistent pseudorandom numbers because they are pulling from a different `RandomState` instance than the one you just created.

If you care about reproducibility, it is highly preferable to structure your code to pass around `RandomState` instances. Global state sucks. C.f. [Consistenly create same random numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836335/consistenly-create-same-random-numpy-array/5837352#5837352)