# How to retrieve the random_state of sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

How to retrieve the random state of `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`?

Without setting the `random_state`, I split my dataset with `train_test_split`. Because the machine learning model trained on the split dataset performs quite well, I want to retrieve the `random_state` that was used to split the dataset. Is there something like `numpy.random.get_state()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trace through the call stack of `train_test_split`, you'll find the `random_state` parameters is used like this:

```
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
rng = check_random_state(self.random_state)
print(rng)
```

The relevant part of `check_random_state` is

```
def check_random_state(seed):
    if seed is None or seed is np.random:
        return np.random.mtrand._rand
```

If `random_state=None`, you get the default `numpy.random.RandomState` singleton, which you can use to generate new random numbers, e.g.:

```
print(rng.permutation(10))
print(rng.randn(10))
```

See these questions for more information:

- [Difference between np.random.seed() and np.random.RandomState()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994423/difference-between-np-random-seed-and-np-random-randomstate)
- [Consistently create same random numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836335/consistently-create-same-random-numpy-array/5837352#5837352)

Comment: So how would I use it in this situation: 

    `kf = KFold(n_splits = 10, shuffle = True, random_state = None)
    rng = check_random_state(self.random_state) `

Because this gives me the following error: `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean?

If you wanna know which random_state you are using, you have to use `random_state` while running the function, for example:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
...     X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

by default its set to `none` see the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Here are also further [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28064634/random-state-pseudo-random-number-in-scikit-learn) to `random_state`.

Or do you mean [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.check_random_state.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I mean is I split my dataset with `train_test_split` without setting the `random_state`, can I retrieve the `random_state` that was used by `train_test_split` afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you only have an old notebook showing a slice of one+ of the train/test subsets (eg `X_test[0:5]`, `y_train[-5:]`, etc), but you know the other parameters (eg [test_size | train_size, shuffle, stratify]) of the `train_test_split()` call and can perfectly recreate `X` and `y`, you could try brute-forcing it by generating new splits with different random_state seeds and comparing the split to your known subset-slice and recording any random_state values producing matching (or close-enough that differences could just be floating-point weirdness) subset-slice values.

```
target_y_train = np.array([-5.482, -11.165, -13.926,  -7.534, -8.323])
possible_random_state_values = []
for i in range(0, 1000):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=i)
    if all(np.isclose(y_train[0:5], target_y_train)):
        possible_random_state_values.append(i)
        print(f"Possible random state value found: {i}")
```

If you don't get any possible seeds from the (0, 1000] range, increase the higher range. And when you get values, you can plug them into train_test_split(), compare other subset_slices if you have any, rerun your model training pipeline, and compare your output metrics.