# How to have multiple numpy random generating objects with different seeds t the same time

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed, seed

To describe what I mean, consider the following dummy example:

```
import numpy as np1
import numpy as np2

seed1 = 1
seed2 = 2

np1.random.seed(seed1)
np2.random.seed(seed2)
```

where `np1.random.normal(0, 2, 1)` returns a value completely regardless of what `seed2` was. (Which of course does not work in this example.

Is there anyway to have such functionality where there are two independent random generating objects?

Comment: Yes, use np.random.RandomState https://stackoverflow.com/a/22995942/2285236 The example uses 42 as the seed for both examples but you can of course set one of them to 1 and the other to 2.

Comment: Note that numpy.random.RandomState is a legacy class as of NumPy 1.17.  That version introduced a new random generator system as well as numpy.random.Generator.  See the [NumPy RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst).

Comment: The newest random number package lets you create multiple independent random number generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent versions, you can make multiple random generators.  See the docs.

To illustrate, make 2 with the same seed:

```
In [5]: r1 =np.random.default_rng(1)
In [6]: r2 =np.random.default_rng(1)
```

They will generate the same random integers without stepping on each other:

```
In [8]: r1.integers(0,10,5)
Out[8]: array([4, 5, 7, 9, 0])
In [9]: r2.integers(0,10,5)
Out[9]: array([4, 5, 7, 9, 0])
```

or several more `r1` sequences:

```
In [10]: r1.integers(0,10,5)
Out[10]: array([1, 8, 9, 2, 3])
In [11]: r1.integers(0,10,5)
Out[11]: array([8, 4, 2, 8, 2])
In [12]: r1.integers(0,10,5)
Out[12]: array([4, 6, 5, 0, 0])
```

Same as Out[10]

```
In [13]: r2.integers(0,10,5)
Out[13]: array([1, 8, 9, 2, 3])
```

Comment: i'd be glad if you could vote up my question so that I won't get suspended...