# Making numpy random draws consistent for reproducability

Tags: python, numpy, random

I would like to be able to fix the sequence of (pseudo) random numbers being generated by `numpy` for reproducability of my research. We can usually achieve this result by fixing the random seed and I followed the same in Python by using `np.random.seed` to fix the value. However, between two Python sessions I am seeing different results for the same random seed. Please find below the output from two sessions.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed = 198908
>>> np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=10)
array([ 0.43203804,  0.89881118,  0.02976592,  0.93286634,  0.21568609,
        0.44705267,  0.27159611,  0.4000281 ,  0.33873711,  0.54835523])
>>> exit()

Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed = 198908
>>> np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=10)
array([ 0.20178185,  0.22492203,  0.51029445,  0.4776532 ,  0.49109006,
        0.22807983,  0.86419725,  0.53422946,  0.08904607,  0.83125896])
>>> exit()
```

Am I missing something here? Also, can anyone suggest an approach that will generate consistent random draws across different machines (assuming same software version is installed)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836335/consistenly-create-same-random-numpy-array/5837352#5837352

Comment: Just curious - does `numpy.random.RandomState()` without any argument also result in consistency across machines or is it only for instances within a machine?

Comment: Calling it without any argument will seed the state completely randomly each time using the OS's cryptographic random number facilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`np.random.seed`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) is a function.  Replace:

```
np.random.seed = 198908
```

With:

```
np.random.seed(198908)
```

#### Details

The argument provided to `seed` can be (1) any integer or (2) an array (or other sequence) of integers of any length, or (3) None.  If it is `None`, then `numpy` will select a seed from the best available random source which on Linux would be `/dev/urandom`.