# How to set the fixed random seed in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I was believing that setting a seed always gives the same result. But I got different result each times.How to set the seed so that we get the same result each time?

Here is the MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


random_state = 100
np.random.state = random_state
np.random.seed = random_state

mu, sigma = 0, 0.25
eps = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,size=100)
print(eps[0])
```

I get different result each times.

### Update:

I can not use np.random.seed(xxx)
[image]

Comment: `np.random.seed(42)` - it's a function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify a random seed while using Python's numpy random choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991675/how-to-specify-a-random-seed-while-using-pythons-numpy-random-choice)

Comment: @SpghttCd, that answer uses np.random.seed(42), but in my case the function is not working.

Comment: @update, because you already overwrote `np.random.seed` by setting it to `100`. Close everything and start again without overwriting. Or perhaps try `del np.random.seed`

Comment: OH! I got it, thanks a lot.

Comment: Another dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309911/making-numpy-random-draws-consistent-for-reproducability

Comment: I _knew_ there would be a user with nickname @update - sorry for disturbing... :)

Comment: @warrenweckesser then not only mention it but flag as dupe, please, so that this here can be closed

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`np.random.seed` is a *function*, which you need to call, **not** assign to it. E.g.:

```
np.random.seed(42)
```

Answer (score 9):

`np.random.seed` is function that sets the random state globally. As an alternative, you can also use `np.random.RandomState(x)` to instantiate a random state class to obtain reproducibility locally. Adapted from your code, I provide an alternative option as follows.

```
import numpy as np
random_state = 100
rng=np.random.RandomState(random_state )
mu, sigma = 0, 0.25
eps = rng.normal(mu,sigma,size=100) # Difference here
print(eps[0])
```

More details on `np.random.seed` and `np.random.RandomState` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994423/difference-between-np-random-seed-and-np-random-randomstate).