# Parallel Process of numpy.random creates same numbers

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I wonder why my program doesn't creates different random number, if I use `Pipe` and `Process` to create them parallel. My code

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

def createNumbers(conn):
    result = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(4))
    conn.send(result)

parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
for i in range(3):
    process = Process(target=createNumbers, args=(child_conn,))
    process.start()
    process.join()
    result = parent_conn.recv()

    print(result)
```

creates three identically vectors

> (0, 1, 1, 1)
>   (0, 1, 1, 1)
>   (0, 1, 1, 1)

If I use `ThreadPool` instead, it works fine. The code

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import numpy as np

def createNumbers():
    return np.random.randint(0,2, size=4)

for i in range(3):
    pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
    process = pool.apply_async(createNumbers)
    result = process.get()
    print(result)
```

creates up to three identically vectors

> (1, 0, 1, 0)
>   (0, 0, 1, 0)
>   (1, 0, 0, 0)

Has someone an idea why the program with `Pipe` and `Process` creates the same numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeding random number generators in parallel programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854398/seeding-random-number-generators-in-parallel-programs)

Comment: np.random.seed() is missing in your code. Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915177/same-output-in-different-workers-in-multiprocessing

Comment: Thanks for both advices. The np.random.seed() does work. I think this is a little weird that Process need to reseed and Threadpool work without it.

Comment: @SebastianH I guess the reason is that processes, when forking, get a copy of the same random state. While threads, in contrast, share a single random state.