# How to use random.RandomState

Tags: python, numpy, random, random-seed

I'd like my script to create the same array of numbers each time I run the script. Earlier I was using np.random.seed(). For example:

```
np.random.seed(1)
X = np.random.random((3,2))
```

I've read that instead of np.random.seed() there should be used RandomState. But I have no idea how to use it, tried some combinations but none worked.

Comment: ...so where did you read that? What's the problem with `np.random.seed`?

Comment: In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836335/consistenly-create-same-random-numpy-array). Look at the second answer and also at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836335/consistenly-create-same-random-numpy-array#comment6702590_5836372)

Comment: What did you try? What output did you get that makes you think it didn't work?

Comment: @RobertKern Something like:
    np.random.RandomState(1)
    np.random.random((3,2))

I just want to know how to use this RandomState, I'm still new to programming, Python and especially NumPy

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's true that it's sometimes advantageous to make sure you get your entropy from a specific (non-global) stream.  Basically, all you have to do is to make a RandomState object and then use its *methods* instead of using numpy's random *functions*.  For example, instead of

```
>>> np.random.seed(3)
>>> np.random.rand()
0.5507979025745755
>>> np.random.randint(10**3, 10**4)
7400
```

You could write

```
>>> R = np.random.RandomState(3)
>>> R
<mtrand.RandomState object at 0x7f79b3315f28>
>>> R.rand()
0.5507979025745755
>>> R.randint(10**3, 10**4)
7400
```

So all you need to do is make `R` and then use `R.` instead of `np.random.` -- pretty simple.  And you can pass R around as you want, and have multiple random streams (if you want a certain process to be the same while another changes, etc.)

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. I've tried to use RandomState in the same way as random.seed, to combine RandomState with numpy functions and it was wrong. Now I understand how to deal with it. Thank you very much.

Comment: What happens if I use `R` without passing any seed? It is the same of using always a random seed?