# Creating multiple graphs using gnp_random_graph

Tags: python, networkx

While using the `NetworkX` package I was tasked with creating multiple random graphs with a given n number of nodes and p probability, this is my code:

```
def random_networks_generator(n,p,num_networks=1, directed=False,seed=30030390):
    Graph_list=[]
    for num in range (0,num_networks):
        G=nx.gnp_random_graph(n,p,seed,directed)
        Graph_list.append(G)
    return Graph_list
```

But, every iteration creates the same exact graph (even the edges are completely the same)

Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong?

**Update:**

After trying to use the function without the "seed" parameter the graphs are random, but is there a way to sort the problem while still using the "seed" parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you make all the calls in the loop with the same fixed seed. According to the documentation of [`gnp_random_graph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.gnp_random_graph.html) or more general [Randomness](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/randomness.html#randomness) by fixing the seed you make sure that you always receive the exactly same random graph.

For example:

```
G_1=nx.gnp_random_graph(100, .5, 42)
G_2=nx.gnp_random_graph(100, .5, 42)
G_3=nx.gnp_random_graph(100, .5, 43)
```

The graphs `G_1` and `G_2` will have exactly the same edges, whereas `G_3` got a different seed and with high likelihood is different (as it is in this example).

You can get the desired behaviour of retrieving the same list of graphs (determined by the initial seed) via the following code:

```
def random_networks_generator(n, p, num_networks=1, directed=False, seed=30030390):
    Graph_list=[]
    for num in range (0,num_networks):
        G=nx.gnp_random_graph(n, p, seed + num, directed)
        Graph_list.append(G)
    return Graph_list
```

More background on seed:

- [What is the use of numpy.random.seed() Does it make any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808660/what-is-the-use-of-numpy-random-seed-does-it-make-any-difference)
- [random.seed(): What does it do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: thank you, you've helped me very much. it was necessary to have a basic understanding of the seed