# Why is Numpy random.uniform not so uniform?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, random-seed

I want to create random points between 0.00001 to 100000 and I tried to use the following code

```
np.random.uniform(0.00001,100000,100)
```

I have two problems. The **first problem** is that I would like to have a random-seed like random_state = 123 such that I can replicate my code. The **second problem** is related to the uniformness of the random.uniform. Despite the name of the function the array does not seem to be drawn from a uniform distribution (see picture).

**EDIT:** I think I didn't explain the second problem correctly. I wanted my values to be evenly distributed from 1e-5 to 1e+5. The result is evenly distributed but it does not contain very small numbers. That is why I changed it to

```
temp = 10 ** np.random.uniform(-5,5,100)
```

which solved the problem that I intended to solve in the second problem.

[image]

Comment: The eye test is not very good for uniformness over such a large interval - look at `np.histogram` with more samples.

Comment: I bet you were expecting a uniform distribution of digit-length, as if rolling a value between 1 and 10 was just as likely as rolling a value between 10000 and 100000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem:** seeding in numpy is done like this

```
>>> from numpy.random import RandomState
>>> rs = RandomState(123)
>>> rs.uniform(0.00001,100000,100)[:3]
array([69646.91856282, 28613.93350218, 22685.14536415])
>>> rs.uniform(0.00001,100000,100)[:3]
array([51312.81542477, 66662.45501974, 10590.84851462])
>>> rs.seed(123)  # resetting state of the PRNG
>>> rs.uniform(0.00001,100000,100)[:3]
array([69646.91856282, 28613.93350218, 22685.14536415])
```

Don't use the `numpy.random.seed` because it sets a global state.  For info on the problems with doing that, check out the comment thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836335/consistently-create-same-random-numpy-array#comment34441123_5836372).

**Second problem:** Looks uniform enough to me.  What's the issue?

Comment: plus 1: Thank you for your answer. You solved the random.seed problem. I think I did not express my second problem properly. I 'solved' it and edited my question.

Comment: @MrYouMath You shouldn't edit the question, you should post an answer